# Didn't redirect to main page after logout

Tags: php

when i click on logout button it's only destroy session and not redirect to main page, it's just stay in that page. any solution?
my logout code:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();
$cookie_timeOut = time() - 86400;  // 1 day  
setcookie("id_relawan", "", $cookie_timeOut, "/");
header('Location: ./');
?>
```

Comment: With this `header('Location: ./');` alone, did it redirect to your expected page?

Comment: Possibly a php warning or error is being displayed, and thus `header()` won't work if any rendered output is put to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `$_SERVER['REQUIST_URI']` global variable. Store the page URI of your current page and store it in session variable and then redirect to logout page. On logout page, assign the previous page url to a variable which you have already stored in a session variable and destroy the session and pass this variable to `header()` to redirect to the previous page.
i.e.

1- Put this code on your current page (except logout page)

```
$_SESSION['previous_page]=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI];
```

2-On logout Page

```
$previous_url=$_SESSION['previous_page'];
```

Now destroy the session and in `header()` pass the `$previous_url` variable to redirect back.

Answer (score 0):

please give complete url you want to redirect

```
$url = '' // Your URL here

header("Location: $url");
```